# How do I use vba to generate a table by combining values from a separate table, based on named entries?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and working on trying to automate a process where a table is generated that displays the total hours worked by a specific person. This data is spread out in an initial table that has 2 columns, one for the workers name, and one for the hours worked. The same name might appear on multiple rows in this initial table, since there can be entries made on different days. I've managed to get to the point that each name found in the Name list ends up only once in the Totals table, but I'm struggling to make it pull the Hours worked values and add them to the specific name. My main thought is that if I can find the cell that is identified by the countif function, then I take that associated $C$? cell for the Hours Worked and add it to Total Hours.
[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHBoV.png)

Thank you "k1dr0ck" for your answer. It works great! I have yet to play around with many of the features of your code, so these will be great tools to learn more about.

Comment: Please show us what code you have already tried. Also tell us what version of Excel you're using, that can make a difference in what native statements are available to you.

Answer (score 0):

example: names and hours is in column A and B starting at row 2 then output in column D and E at row 2

```
Sub SumValues()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not dict.Exists(cell.value) Then
            dict.Add cell.value, 0
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Dim matchCell As Range
    For Each matchCell In rng
        If dict.Exists(matchCell.value) Then
            dict(matchCell.value) = dict(matchCell.value) + Cells(matchCell.Row, "B").value
        End If
    Next matchCell
    
    Dim outputRow As Long
    outputRow = 2
    
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Cells(outputRow, "D").value = key
        Cells(outputRow, "E").value = dict(key)
        outputRow = outputRow + 1
    Next key
End Sub
```